# regex = False doesn't exist in str.split

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, split

I am trying to split strings in my column using str.split: `str.split(".  ", regex = False)`. But when I do that, I get error:

`split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'`

why it happens? regex should exist in that method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: You seem to be confusing Pandas with regular Python. How is `str` defined? A basic Python string does not have that keyword argument.

Comment: @tripleee i apply it to column with strings. it is pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: The error message does not seem to bear this out. Please review the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

`str.split` is a function in the `str` (string) class.

You want to use: `my_series.str.split(".  ", regex = False)`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"test": ["abc  ABC", "def  DEF"]})

df["test"].str.split(".  ", regex=True)
```

gives

```
0        [ab, ABC]
1        [de, DEF]
Name: test, dtype: object
```